# Error : typeInitializationException

Tags: c#, autocad, objectarx

I've found a code to open a dwg file in autocad with objectARX commands.this code works successfully when i wrote it in a Class Library project, but the problem is happened when i want to place this code in my windows application.It gives me this error message :

> The type initializer for '< Module >' threw an exception.
>
> Inner Exception : The C++ module failed to load during process
> initialization.

my code is :

```
String MyDWGFilePath = @"\\Server\SharedFolder\Projects\File1.dwg";
DocumentCollection dm = Application.DocumentManager;
Document doc = null;
 
if(File.Exists(MyDWGFilePath))
{
   doc = dm.Open(MyDWGFilePath, false);
   Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument = doc;
}
```

**Note:** I've add acdbmgd.dll and acmgd.dll from autocad installed folder and also AutoCAD and AXDBLib from COM references.

please help me...

Comment: did you tried adding class library as reference to windows project and then call the function in class library that opens dwg file?

Comment: yes,but i received that error again.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that Autodesk riggs some (but not all*) of their AutoCAD libraries to not be runnable outside of an AutoCAD address space.  You may be running into this licensing restriction.  (I am crawling Autodesk's web site for a reference to back this up).

Edit:  [RealDWG](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=770257) is the product Autodesk wants you to buy if you are going to do .dwg manipulation outside of AutoCAD.  (Still looking for the AcDbMgd only operates inside of acad link...)

(*)  I know that the AcGe group of classes/dlls are usable outside of AutoCAD - I used to use them in some unit testing.  I think that anything manipulating the .dwg database must run inside of AutoCAD.

Comment: Hi @rschuler,Thanks for your reply.Excuse me but i did not understand your meaning of "must run inside of AutoCAD"? and why my code is running successfully in a class library but has error in win. app.? in the addition i think the problem is with AcMgd.dll not AcDbMgd.dll.

Comment: The AutoCAD application loads the managed dlls. They cannot be used outside of AutoCAD. They are only wrappers for internal functions, they are not AutoCAD itself. You cannot write a .exe application that uses AutoCAD DLLs. The AcGe loophole is news to me, Interesting.

Comment: This link (http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer%27s%20Guide/files/WS73099cc142f48755-5c83e7b1120018de8c0-2202.htm) explains standalone vs in-process AutoCAD extensions. It also provides a method of creating a standalone app but you still need to have AutoCAD installed on your machine and you need to create an instance. RealDWG is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

maybe check target framework for windows project, change it to .Net Framework x, if it is set to .Net framework client profile

Comment: Are you using AutoCAD 2012? that is the only one compiled against .NET 4 so far

Answer (score 0):

[RealDWG](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=770257) is what you need.

In RealDWG documentation:

*The basic steps to set up a .NET solution using Visual Studio and the ObjectARX managed wrappers are the same whether you use Microsoft Visual C# .NET or Visual Basic .NET.*

**To begin using the ObjectARX managed wrappers with Microsoft Visual Studio**

1. In Visual Studio .NET, create a class library solution and project.
2. Select Add Reference from the Project menu or Solution Explorer.
3. Browse to the \inc directory of the ObjectARX SDK and select
   acdbmgd.dll and acmgd.dll.
4. In the main class file, add the namespaces you will use.

For example, in C#:

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
```

In VB .NET:

```
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.RuntimeThe
```

ObjectARX SDK provides .NET samples in the \samples\dotNet directory.

Topics in this section

- Defining AutoCAD Commands in Managed Applications
- Defining Methods That Can Be Called From AutoLISP
- Using Instance and Static Command Methods
- Loading Managed Applications in AutoCAD
- Managing Exceptions in Managed Applications
- Using Transactions in Managed Applications
- Using the ResultBuffer Type
- Managing Selection Sets
- User Interface Access with Managed Classes
- Using Managed Application Initialization and Load-Time Optimization